# SelectedIndex ComboBox binding using EnumBindingSourceExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using Brian Laguna's [solution](https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/)  to bind a WPF ComboBox `ItemSource` to an `Enum`:

```
public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public EnumBindingSourceExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        if (enumType == null || !enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new Exception("EnumType must not be null and of type Enum");
        }

        this.EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public Type EnumType { get; private set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(this.EnumType);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="NoiseModelTypeComboBox"              
           SelectedIndex="1"               
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={sharedPt:EnumBindingSource {x:Type dataModel:NoiseModelType}}}"
           SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedNoiseModelType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

in my vm `SelectedNoiseModelType` is of Type `string`. I wan't to set a default value on construction i.e. `SelectedIndex` but this does not work presumably due to the `ItemSource` binding not being a collection in the vm. Any way to achieve the default selected index?

Comment: "is of Type string" - shouldn't this be rather of type `NoiseModelType`?

Comment: @KlausGütter this results in 'Value could not be converted' on selection changed so probably need to use a converter to the enum value.

Comment: Just tested it: with `NoiseModelType SelectedNoiseModelType` in the view model it works fine for me. If the property is initialized to any enum value, it will be selected in the combo box.

Comment: @KlausGütter are you binding the ItemSource to EnumBindingSourceExtension as above?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you do. I posted my code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The items in the combobox will be of type `NoiseModelType`, and so are the values (as you do not specify a `SelectedValuePath`).
This means that also the property bound to `SelectedValue` (or `SelectedItem`) must be of this type.

So change your SelectedNoiseModelType property from `string` to:

```
public NoiseModelType SelectedNoiseModelType 
{
    get => _selectedNoiseModelType;
    set 
    { 
        // whatever the MVVM framework of your choice offers 
        // for setting a value with PropertyChanged norification
    }
}
```

When the property is initialized to any enum value, the ComboBox will initially come up with this item selected. I would recommend to remove the `SelectedIndex="1"` from the XAML to be clear by what the initial selection is determined.